# Encoding huge categorical features

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I am currently working on a **big** **categorical** dataset using both Pandas an sklearn. As I want know to do feature extraction, or just be able to build a model, I need to encode the categoricals features as they are not handled by sklearn models.

Here is the issue : for one of the categories, I have more than 110,000 different values. I cannot possibly encode this as there would be (and there is) a **memory error**.
Also, this feature **cannot** be removed from the DataSet so this option is out of the question.

So I have multiple ways to deal with that :

- Use FeatureHasher from sklearn (as mentionned in several topics related to that). But, while it's easy to encode, there is no mention on how to link the hashed feature with the DataFrame and thus, complete the feature extraction.
- Use FuzzyMatching to reduce the number or values in the features and then use one-hot-encoding. The issue here is that it'll still create many dummy variables and I will lose the interest regarding the features that get encoded.

So I have multiple questions : first, do you know how to use FeatureHasher to link a Pandas DataFrame to an sklearn model through hashing ? If so, how am I supposed to do it ?
Second, can you think of any other way to do it that might be easier, or would work best with my problem?

---

Here are some screenshots regarding the DataSet I have, so that you understand more fully the issue.
[Here is the output of the number/percentage of different values per feature.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6gQP.png)

Also, the values inside the biggest feature to encode called 'commentaire' (commentary in english) contains strings that sometimes are long sentences and sometimes just small words.

---

As requested, here is the current code to test **Feature Hashing**:

```
fh = FeatureHasher(input_type='string')
hashedCommentaire = fh.transform(dataFrame['commentaire'])
```

This outputs a Memory Error, so I can reduce the number of features, let's put it at a 100:

```
fh = FeatureHasher(input_type='string', n_features=100)
hashedCommentaire = fh.transform(dataFrame['commentaire'])
print(hashedCommentaire.toarray())
print(hashedCommentaire.shape)
```

It doesn't get an error and outputs the following : [feature hashing output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWApJ.png)

Can I then directly use the result hashing in my DataFrame? The issue is that we totally loose track of the values of 'commentaire', if we then want to predict on new data, will the hashing output follow the previous one ? And also how do we know the hashing is "sufficient". Here I put 100 rows but there was more than 110,000 values to begin with.

---

Thanks to another observation, I began to explore the use of **tf-idf**. Here we can see a sample of 'commentaire' values: ['commentaire' feature sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hQfC.png) 
As we can see the different values will be strings. Sometimes sentences. The thing is, while exploring this data, I noticed that some values are very close to each other; that's why I wanted to explore the idea of Fuzzy Matching at first and now of tf-idf.

Comment: Rather than encoding the strings it might be worth doing some NLP with them instead. Something like tf-idf might be a good place to start.

Comment: @ncfirth i'll be checking that out, thank you!

Comment: "how to link the hashed feature with the DataFrame and thus, complete the feature extraction."   Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: @BertKellerman well I tried using the FeatureHasher of sklearn on the feature 'commentaire' on which I'm currently working. 
And the output is a sparse matrix but I couldn't find the way to use it to modify my dataframe column based on its output.

Comment: With feature hashing, each categorical column will be transformed into many sparse columns.  Please post your code that you have so far and any errors you are getting.

Comment: @BertKellerman edited to answer you!